Macro to update values per row
I figured out how to update the cells how I need using a macro on a per row basis, but I need to apply it to all rows on the spreadsheet in an efficient way.
Users will enter a quantity in Column G on a per row basis. The macro will update the value Column H to include the quantity that was entered in column G. Then the macro clears the contents of Column G.
For example, user enters quantity "1" in G3. There is an existing value of "5" in H3. When I run the macro H3 updates to quantity of "6", and clears the value from G3.
I have the macro working for row 3, and tested adding a separate sub for row 4. How can I write this more efficiently so it will apply to the range of columns G and H starting at row 3?
My current macro which works for Rows 3 and 4.
Sub UpdateQty()
'
' UpdateQty Macro
'

'
    Range("H3") = Range("G3") + Range("H3")
        
    Range("G3").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
 
    
        Range("H4") = Range("G4") + Range("H4")
        
    Range("G4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("I4").Select
End Sub


Using an array would be an efficient way to do this.

Iterate down your cells after variablizing your cells. Meaning, you define the lastrow and iterate from your beginning row like For i = 3 to LastRow then apply your logic, Sheets("sheet1").cells(i, 8).value = Sheets("sheet1").cells(i, 7).value + Sheets("sheet1").cells(i, 8).value

Using array is a more efficient approach to process data as @BigBen suggested.
Microsoft documentation:

Range.End property (Excel)


Len function


IsNumeric function

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, arrData, rngData As Range
    Const START_ROW = 3
    Set rngData = Range("G" & START_ROW, Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        iVal = arrData(i, 2)
        If Len(iVal) > 0 And IsNumeric(iVal) Then
            arrData(i, 1) = arrData(i, 1) + iVal
            arrData(i, 2) = ""
        End If
    Next i
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub


Thank you. It turns out I wont be able to use a macro for this project for an unrelated reason but I appreciate the solution, will be very handy in the future!
